# How to Compile boost with GCC 5 using old ABI?

Tags: c++11, gcc, boost, linker, abi

I have downloaded a library that was compiled with a gcc 4.8 before the ABI change in GCC.

On my laptop (latest kubuntu) I have GCC 5.2. And When I installed boost, it seems that it used the new ABI but then I get the following link errors

undefined symbol.....__cxx11....

How can I install boost using old ABI with GCC5 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no prebuilt Boost packages for the old ABI in the official Kubuntu repositories, so you will have to build Boost yourself. The building process is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Make sure you're building the same Boost version that was used when your library was built. If there were any Boost configuration macros defined, you will also have to define them the similar way. Otherwise you may encounter ABI incompatibilities between the library and Boost you've built.

In order to switch libstdc++ to the old ABI you will also have to define `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to 0, as described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html). For example:

```
b2 -j8 variant=release define=_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 stage
```

You will also need to define the macro when you build your own code that uses Boost and the library.

The `define` property, along with many others, is documented [here](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties).

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer. "define" was the config option i was looking for. I would like to add this link for those who might need other options. http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html