# Boost Serialization Linking error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm trying to compile some 6-month old code, but I'm running into a linker error with boost libraries (particularly `boost:serialization`):

```
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:88: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm sure this code was compilable a while ago (I am linking with boost libraries with `-lboost_serialization`), and the only thing that changed was the boost version (currently 1.60) and recently I had some issues with GCC's dual ABI (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) - could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, IME that is precisely the problem there. Sometimes you just need a full rebuild. Otherwise you need to rebuild the boost libs with the same flags/toolchain

Comment: I have to use the older (pre-std-c++11) ABI due to some older 3rd party code (`#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0`) but how do I tell boost to use it as well?

Comment: That's a good question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309021/how-to-compile-boost-with-gcc-5-using-old-abi

Comment: Let me know if that answered your question

Comment: @sehe It did, thank you very much.